# Add data to a dataframe column from another dataframe with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes:

df1:

```
name surname
jane doe
john doe
```

df2

```
name
james
```

I want to add df2 to df1:

df_final

```
name    surname 
james   doe
jane    doe
john
```

with `df1.add(df2)` I haven't correct result. how can I add df2's data to first column of df1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `append` to do that i.e

```
df2.append(df1)
```

Output :

```
  name surname
0  james     NaN
0   jane     doe
1   john     doe
```

For your expected output you can do

```
df2.append(df).apply(sorted,key=pd.isnull).fillna('')
```

```
  name surname
0  james     doe
0   jane     doe
1   john
```